How to use the build of one react app inside another react application?
I have created a build of a react app and now I want to use it in another(parent) react app. But when I am trying to run the parent app it is throwing minified react error #299 that the div is not currently in the DOM. I have tried setting setTimeout but it still is not working
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import childScript from "build/static/js/main.80074925";
export default function ChildComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadScript = () => {
      // Create a script element
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = childScript; // Replace with the correct path
      script.async = true;

      // Callback function to be executed after the script is loaded
      script.onload = () => {
        // After the script is loaded, mount the child app into the child-root div
        const childRoot = document.getElementById("child-root");
        if (childRoot && window.ChildApp) {
          // Ensure the child-root div exists and the child app is available
          window.ChildApp.mount(childRoot); // Assuming you have a mount function in your child app
        }
      };

      // Append the script to the document body
      document.body.appendChild(script);

      // Clean up function to remove the script element when the component is unmounted
      return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      };
    };

    // Load the script after 2 seconds
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(loadScript, 2000);

    // Clean up function to clear the timeout when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to run the effect only once

  return <div id="child-root"></div>;
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
